# Going to specific part of a webpage using anchor name attribute by loading view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor

Using `<a name="form"></a>` and then going to that position by `<a href="#form">Click here</a>`
In code-igniter, I'm trying to load a view and a specific part of that view ie., `<a name="form"></a>`. It can be easily done by redirecting to that page using the #name but that clears up the form validation errors.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    $this->add();
}
```

where `add()` is the function which loads the view.

```
public function add()
{
    $data['main_content'] = "add_view";
    $data['css_code'] = "add_view.css";
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Found the answer at last.
You just have to add the anchor to the URI in `form_open()`

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/function#anchor'); ?>
```

Reference [Codeigniter Forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/119231/#590064)